# How to pass props to ng-content?

Tags: angular

I have `app-address-form` form component, inside of it was created reactive form object, I want to get access to this form object from ng-content place, like:

```
<app-address-form let-form>
   <button [disabled]="form.valid">
</app-address-form>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Hello. Yuriy. Can you share more code ? like in which component did you used `app-address-form` and whats inside `app-address-form` component code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> address-form.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-form',
  templateUrl: './address-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-form.component.scss'],
})
export class AppAddressFormComponent {
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef, { static: false }) buttonsTemplate: TemplateRef<{disabled: boolean, close: () => void}>;

  addressForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('',  [Validators.required]),
    lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });


  cancel(): void {
    this.cancel.emit();
  }
}
```

> address-form.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
   <div class="form-row" ...>
   <div class="form-row" ...>
   <div class="form-row" ...>
   <div class="form-row" ...>
      <ng-container *ngIf="buttonsTemplate">
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="buttonsTemplate; context: { disabled: !addressForm.valid || !addressForm.touched, cancel: cancel}">
         </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
   </div>
</form>
```

> Usage

```
<app-address-form
  [type]="type"
  (addressChanged)="addAddress($event)"
>
  <ng-template #buttonsTemplate let-cancel="cancel" let-disabled="disabled">
    <button class="form-control-button save" type="submit" [disabled]="disabled">
      {{'addressForm.saveAddress'}}
    </button>
    <button class="form-control-button cancel" type="reset" (click)="cancel()">
      {{'common.cancel'}}
    </button>
  </ng-template>
</app-address-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [TemplateRef](https://inglkruiz.github.io/templateref-projection-with-context-inside-component/) projection with Context in an Angular Component -

Comment: Hi vzl the link you gave although related to the question requires a bit of digging to understand.. perhaps you could provide a more simple example thereby showing that you understand the answer too :-)